# Criar um BufferedImage a partir de um Array de int

Tags: java, imagem

tenho um array unidimensional que contém as cores de uma imagem, onde a cada intervalo de 3 posições é representado a cor de um pixel (R,G,B):

```
int[] cores = {255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255};
```

Neste array eu teria 3 pixels, onde o primeiro seria [255, 0, 0] (Vermelho), o segundo [0, 255, 0] (Verde) e por fim [0, 0, 255] (Azul). A partir deste array, estou criando uma BufferedImage, tentando passar este array como parâmetro, porém não entendi a utilidade dos parâmetros offset e scansize (os dois últimos parâmetros passados ao setRGB).

```
BufferedImage rendered = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), this.imageType);

rendered.setRGB(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this.getData(), 0, this.getWidth());
```

A imagem criada gera apenas pixels com a cor azul, gostaria de saber se é possível passar este array como parâmetro ou se vou ter que setar pixel por pixel a nova imagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não use o setRGB, pois embora funcione, será menos eficiente (pois estará setando um pixel por vez). Use o `getRaster().getDataBuffer()` da imagem para ter um acesso ao array de pixels diretamente.

O problema de ser apenas azul deve ter algo a ver com o canal Alpha. As cores são codificados em um int único (e não em três ou quatro, considerando o Alpha/transparência), então tem que fazer uma conversão. Fiz um ajuste no código para ficar eficiente e dar o resultado correto:

```
    int[] cores = { 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255,
                    255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255,
                    255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255,
                    255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255,
                    255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255
                                                    };

    // Converte array de origem em um array RGB
    int argb[] = new int[cores.length/3];
    for(int i=0; i<cores.length; i+=3) {
       argb[i/3] = -16777216; // 255 alpha
       argb[i/3] += (((int) cores[i] & 0xff) << 16); // vermelho
       argb[i/3] += (((int) cores[i+1] & 0xff) << 8); // verde
       argb[i/3] += ((int) cores[i+2] & 0xff); // azul
    }

    int larguraImagem = 3;
    int alturaImagem = 5;

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(larguraImagem, alturaImagem, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
    final int[] a = ( (DataBufferInt) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer() ).getData();
    System.arraycopy(argb, 0, a, 0, argb.length);
```

A saída será uma imagem de 3x5 com uma linha de cada cor (amplificada abaixo em 50 vezes):

[image: Saída do programa]